# Is CascadeType.MERGE required for @OneToOne?

Tags: jpa, merge, cascade, one-to-one

With following decoration and conditions,

```java
/**
 * passsalt.
 */
@JoinColumn(name = "PASSSALT_ID", nullable = false)
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,
                     CascadeType.MERGE, // is this actually required?
                     CascadeType.REMOVE},
          optional = false, orphanRemoval = true)
@NotNull
@XmlTransient
private Morton passsalt;
```

- `passsalt` must persited along with this entity. (`CascadeType.PERSIST`)
- `passsalt` can be replaced with a new `detached` instance. (`CascadeType.MERGE`?)
- `passsalt` must be removed when this entity removed. (`CascadeType.REMOVE`)
- `Morton` has no fields to be updated

QUESTION: Does `CascadeType.MERGE` is mandatory?

I tested with and without `CascadeType.MERGE` and it seems work without it.

Q2: Is "Is" is right in the question title? Is it should be "Does"?

Here is a method for replacing `passsalt`.

```java
public boolean nassword(final Shadow reference, final byte[] password,
                        final byte[] nassword) {

    passsalt = new Morton();
    passcode = passsalt.salty(nassword);

    return true;
}
```

I tested in following method.

```java
@Test(enabled = true, invocationCount = 1)
public void testNassword0() {
    final EntityManager manager = LocalPU.createEntityManager();
    try {
        final EntityTransaction transaction = manager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        try {
            final String username = newUsername(manager);
            final byte[] password = newPassword();
            Shadow shadow = persistInstance(manager, username, password);
            Assert.assertTrue(shadow.puthenticate(shadow, password));
            System.out.println("=========================================");
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "mortons: {0}",
                       MORTONS(manager, 0, 1024));
            final byte[] nassword = newPassword();
            shadow.nassword(shadow, password, nassword);
            shadow = manager.merge(shadow);
            manager.flush();
            System.out.println("=========================================");
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "mortons: {0}",
                       MORTONS(manager, 0, 1024));
            Assert.assertFalse(shadow.puthenticate(shadow, password));
            Assert.assertTrue(shadow.puthenticate(shadow, nassword));
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the output.

```
4월 02, 2013 11:55:03 오전 org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
[EL Info]: 2013-04-02 11:55:03.897--ServerSession(571229670)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
[EL Info]: 2013-04-02 11:55:04.744--ServerSession(571229670)--file:/E:/svnwc/jinahya.googlecode.com/trunk/com.googlecode.jinahya/jinahya-ee/target/test-classes/_localPU login successful
4월 02, 2013 11:55:06 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.Morton _PrePersist
INFO: _PrePersist(): Morton@1760972179&id=1048576
4월 02, 2013 11:55:06 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.Shadow puthenticate
INFO: puthenticate(Shadow@1311874806?id=1048576&username=0KIWHFirmA581Qf5AscsrVbN9YW30pAF&passcode=[B@57d01cc, [B@5200fae4)
4월 02, 2013 11:55:06 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.Shadow puthenticate
INFO: passsalt: Morton@1760972179&id=1048576
=========================================
4월 02, 2013 11:55:08 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.ShadowTest testNassword0
INFO: mortons: [Morton@1760972179&id=1048576]
4월 02, 2013 11:55:08 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.Shadow nassword
INFO: nassword(Shadow@1311874806?id=1048576&username=0KIWHFirmA581Qf5AscsrVbN9YW30pAF&passcode=[B@57d01cc, [B@5200fae4, [B@1b6ac76b)
4월 02, 2013 11:55:08 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.Shadow puthenticate
INFO: puthenticate(Shadow@1311874806?id=1048576&username=0KIWHFirmA581Qf5AscsrVbN9YW30pAF&passcode=[B@57d01cc, [B@5200fae4)
4월 02, 2013 11:55:08 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.Shadow puthenticate
INFO: passsalt: Morton@1760972179&id=1048576
4월 02, 2013 11:55:11 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.Morton _PrePersist
INFO: _PrePersist(): Morton@93935309&id=1048577
=========================================
4월 02, 2013 11:55:11 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.ShadowTest testNassword0
INFO: mortons: [Morton@93935309&id=1048577]
4월 02, 2013 11:55:11 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.Shadow puthenticate
INFO: puthenticate(Shadow@1311874806?id=1048576&username=0KIWHFirmA581Qf5AscsrVbN9YW30pAF&passcode=[B@641e8314, [B@5200fae4)
4월 02, 2013 11:55:11 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.Shadow puthenticate
INFO: passsalt: Morton@93935309&id=1048577
4월 02, 2013 11:55:12 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.Shadow puthenticate
INFO: puthenticate(Shadow@1311874806?id=1048576&username=0KIWHFirmA581Qf5AscsrVbN9YW30pAF&passcode=[B@641e8314, [B@1b6ac76b)
4월 02, 2013 11:55:12 오전 com.googlecode.jinahya.persistence.Shadow puthenticate
INFO: passsalt: Morton@93935309&id=1048577
```

In summary,

```
After persisted ->           mortons: [Morton@1760972179&id=1048576]
After replaced and merged -> mortons: [Morton@93935309&id=1048577]
```

Comment: Did you test with a detached object? That actually contained an instance of `Morton`?

Comment: Yes, I believe. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, it is not required.

Cascade persist and merge are separate things.  Cascade Persist is used when you call persist on the owning entity, causing persist to be called on the referenced passsalt as well.  If cascade persist is on the relationship, it is implied that referencing a new object will be found when flush or commit will be called as well.

Merge on the other hand applies to the merge operation in the same way.  When you call merge on the entity, it will cause merge to also be called on the passsalt.  If it exists and is just detached, changes will be picked up.  If it is new, it will be inserted similar to if persist was called.  What happens when cascade merge is not specified and the relationship references a detached object is covered by the spec, but seems grey as to what happens if the entity is new.  It states that the returning owning entity references a managed instance of passsalt, which implies that it would be inserted anyway since managed instances are required to be synchronized with the database on flush or commit.  So it should have no effect, but depending on how you are using the merge api and how your JPA provider behaves, you may want to keep it set.  Not having it means changes to the existing passsalt (if you did not just replace it of course) would not have been picked up.

Also, you are using orphanRemoval, so cascade remove is implied and not needed.  OrphanRemoval means that the referenced passsalt cannot exist without the owner entity, so when the owner is removed or dereferences the passsalt, it will get deleted from the database without the need for the cascade removal setting.